# Mean removing NAs inside vectors in R with ! operator

Tags: r, na

I am stuck with a problem in R.
It is about removing NAs within vectors and dataframes.

I am given the library, data frame and the vector as follows:

```
library(dslabs)
data(na_example)
ind <- is.na(na_example)
```

So, I need to compute the mean, but with the entries that are not `NA` inside the vector `"ind"`.

I have tried everything, including the answer (I think) that is: `mean(!ind)`, because I HAVE to use the `!` operator.

The result is 0.855. However, the evaluating system does not give me a positive score.

Please, could you give me a hand?

Comment: You can try `ind <- na.omit(na_example)` which will give you all values that are not `NA`, instead of the boolean results of `is.na`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `na.omit`, not `is.na`:

```
library(dslabs)
data(na_example)
ind <- na.omit(na_example)

mean(ind)
```

Which gives you: 2.301754

Comment: Which turns out in: 2.301754.

Comment: Yes, I know the na.omit() function, but I am meant to use the ! operator, so therefore, I got stuck at this point. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

So, I finally got after many hours of struggle.

I was putting the ! in the wrong place

```
ind <- is.na(na_example)
mean(!ind)
[1] 0.855
```

It should be:

```
ind <- !is.na(na_example)
mean(ind)
[1] 0.855
```